# How does Windows link HTML files to folders?

Tags: html, windows, directory

Almost every time you save a web page from a web browser to your local computer a *PAGENAME.html* (or .htm) file is created and a folder named 'PAGENAME_files' that contains resources specific to that page.

If you copy/move/delete either the folder or the .html file Windows automatically does the same operation the other file as well.

This behaviour also happens if you create a file named *1.html* and a folder called *1_files*.

How does this link happen? And *why* does it work only with web files?

Comment: This would seem on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), not Stack Overflow .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a shell feature, not a file system feature. The shell copy engine just looks for a folder with the same name (plus a localized suffix) when copying/moving .htm[l] files.

This feature is called Connected Files and is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/manage#connected-files).

Answer (score 5):

It's a built-in linkage in Windows.

Open up Explorer (not IE, Windows), Tools, Options, View, then in Advanced Settings there'll be a "Managing pairs of Web pages and folders" section.

Comment: Well that's some really hidden stuff. On Windows 7 I had to enable that "Managing pairs of Web pages and folders" section from registry as it was not there by default. And there is no Advanced Settings.

Comment: In Win10 the "Advanced Settings" is at the end of the "View" tab in the ribbon, but this option is gone. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/delete-html-file-without-deleting-resource-files/295d8767-b6fa-4e65-ad87-ff8bae659811

Comment: It seems to me there’s not a easy way like mac or/and linux-unix, etc… where you define a public_html folder or Sites folder in Mac.  That’s annoying i always see the prefix files when i see a web page.

Answer (score 4):

If people are stuck and ended up here to find how to unlink, here's an easy trick : on Windows 10, I couldn't find how to unlink a .html file from its associated media folder, so I deleted both of them, and in the bin I restored only the .html file and it was then restored and unlinked from its folder.

Comment: On Windows 10 Pro (v 1809, build 17763.437), when I rename either the html file or the folder, it warns me that the corresponding file/folder will no longer "belong" to each other, etc., etc.  But if Okay is clicked, the rename occurs are the file and folder become unlinked and can be moved, deleted or renamed independently.  No need to go through a process of first deleting them, then restore.  Perhaps this is only a recent feature update.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question.

Under Windows 7 I managed to solve forced links by simply renaming the file.

I think it is the easiest way.